# Android Contextual ActionBar and ListView multiselect support in MonoDroid: where is ChoiceMode.MultipleModal?

Tags: android, android-listview, xamarin.android, android-actionbar

To enable CAB support for ListView I need to set ListView.ChoiceMode to ChoiceMode.MultipleModal which is absent in ChoiceMode enum in MonoDroid. How to enable CAB supoort in this case? Wait for next version of MonoDroid or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's in Android.Widget.AbsListViewChoiceMode.

So you'll need:

`myList.ChoiceMode = (ChoiceMode)AbsListViewChoiceMode.MultipleModal`

Comment: Thanks. This is strange that there are two different enums responsible to same things. Unneeded casting can cause unexpected runtime errors.